# Google Bigquery - Bulk Load

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a csv file with 300 columns. Size is approx 250 MB. Trying to upload it to BQ through Web UI but the schema specification is hard work. I was anticipating BQ will identify file headers but it doesn't seems to be recognising unless I am missing something.Is there a way forward ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have to write the schema by your own. Bigquery is not able to auto-infert it. If you have 300 columns, I sugget writing a script to automatically create the schema.

With the command-line tool (cf [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool)) If you have some lines with the wrong/different schema, you can use the following option to continue for other records :

```
--max_bad_records : The maximum number of bad rows to skip before the load job
```

In your case if you want to skip the first line of headers, that can be the following :

```
bq load --skip_leading_rows=1 --max_bad_records=10000 <destination_table> <data_source_uri> [<table_schema>]
```